# How to differentiate a modulus?

Tags: calculus

How to differentiate something like this:
\begin{aligned} \large
\ (\ln |Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|)'
\end{aligned}
If it would something like that:
\begin{aligned} \large
\ (\ln |Ax-B|)'
\end{aligned}
Could I just split in something like this:
\begin{aligned} \large
\ (\ln (Ax-B))' + (\ln(Ax+B))'
\end{aligned}
And differentiate it then?

Comment: Are you having problems differentiating the logarithm or the modulus. The modulus is in there to tell you that logarithms blush if they saw negative people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).
$$\begin{eqnarray}(ln |Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|)'&=&\frac{1}{|Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|}|Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|'\\
&=&\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D})}{|Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|}(Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D})'\\
&=&\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D})}{|Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}|}\left(A+\frac{1}{2}\frac{C}{\sqrt{Cx+D}}\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{Ax+B + \sqrt{Cx-D}}\left(A+\frac{1}{2}\frac{C}{\sqrt{Cx+D}}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 3):

The most useful fact is that the derivative of $\ln|x|$ is $1/x$ (most easily checked by considering $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately). Your function is a composition of this and another function. Use the chain rule.